# How do I make a simple user-editable table in an R Shiny app using modular design?

Tags: r, shiny, module, shinyapps

I see some solutions with DT, but this is really kind of overkill and I want the easy ability for the user to add/ delete and move rows around and be able to access these manipulations for other parts of my app.

I would also like to implement this as a reusable module to cut down on code complexity.
A simple example with mtcars[1:5,] would be great.

Comment: Are you aware of `DataEditR`. Could be useful. `my_mtcars <- mtcars[1:5, ]

DataEditR::data_edit(my_mtcars)`

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I checked that out, but I couldn't figure out how to get the shiny module working for an existing dataframe...it seems to really be set up for working with an imported CSV...I'm just looking for a simple shiny input for tabular data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up piecing together a solution using the `rhandsontable` library. Here is an example with moveable rows and editable cells connected to tabular output that can easily be fed and interpreted in the R environment:
[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
require(rhandsontable)



#------

#Definition of UI part of ediTable module

ediTable <- function(id, ...) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  rHandsontableOutput(outputId = ns("hot"), ...)
  
}

#Server logic for the module

ediTable_server <-
  function(id,
           rd,
           allowRowEdit = TRUE,
           allowColumnEdit = FALSE,
           manualRowMove = TRUE,
           ...) {
    moduleServer(id,
                 function(input, output, session) {
                   output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
                     tmp <- isolate(rd())#Gotta isolate it or it'll cause infinite loop
                      #Necessary to avoid the issue described [here](https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/issues/166)
                     rownames(tmp) <- NULL
                     rhandsontable(
                       tmp,
                       allowRowEdit = allowRowEdit,
                       allowColumnEdit = allowColumnEdit,
                       manualRowMove = manualRowMove,
                       ...
                     )
                     
                   })
                   
                   #Update the reactive values for this user-manipulated data to pass back to main environment
                   observeEvent(input$hot, {
                     
                     tmp <- rhandsontable::hot_to_r(input$hot)
                     
                     rd(tmp)
                     
                     
                   })
                   
                 })
  }



# Define UI for the main application
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("ediTable: editable table widget"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h3("Motivation:"),
      p(
        "Sometimes you just want to allow users to edit a table and then save that input data."
      ),
      p(
        "This is basically a shallow, more intuitive wrapper for rhandsontable."
      )
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      h1("Table 1: a reactive module"),
      p("Double click a cell to edit."),
      p("Right click to add or remove rows; click and drag to move."),
      ediTable(id = "tab"),
      h3("Outputting the edited data for Table 1"),
      tableOutput("data1"),
      h1("Table 2: independently reactive module"),
      ediTable(id = "tab2"),
      h3("Outputting the edited data for Table 1"),
      tableOutput("data2")
      
      
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic for the main application
server <- function(input, output) {
  init_data <- head(mtcars)
  reactive_data1 <-  reactiveVal(init_data)
  reactive_data2 <-  reactiveVal(init_data)
  
  ediTable_server(id = "tab", rd = reactive_data1)
  
  ediTable_server(id = "tab2",  rd = reactive_data2)
  
  observe({
    tmp <- reactive_data1()
    output$data1 <-
    tmp %>% renderTable()
  
  })
  observe({
   tmp2 <- reactive_data2()
  output$data2 <- tmp2 %>% renderTable()
    })

  
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this: taken from https://dillonhammill.github.io/DataEditR/reference/dataEdit.html

```
if (interactive()) {

  library(shiny)
  library(DataEditR)
    ui <- fluidPage(
    dataInputUI("input-1"),
    dataOutputUI("output-1"),
    dataEditUI("edit-1")
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    data_to_edit <- dataInputServer("input-1")
    data_edit <- dataEditServer("edit-1",
                                data = data_to_edit
    )
    dataOutputServer("output-1",
                     data = data_edit
    )
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but I wasn't able to successfully feed data into the dataEditServer as a reactiveVal(). I'm not sure how it's working in this example. Is the user typing in mtcars in the "Data to edit" field? I don't want the user to do any selection on inputs here–just effectively a table version of a shiny::textAreaInput().